# Jquery Datatable Entity Framework Checkbox UPDATE database

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I added a check box for each row in my DataTable. The user should click approve and the rows that are "checked" should have status change to "Approved". So far this works in the database by using AJAX. But I want to change the data value in the VIEW without reloading the table data.

Is there some way to write a Javascript to change row[x].status = Approved if CheckBox is checked and then the Approve button is clicked?

[image]

```
enter code here     $(document).ready(function () {

    var table = $('#provider_contracts').DataTable({
        "scrollX": true,
        initComplete: function () {

            this.api().columns([1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]).every(function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select class="select_option" "><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                    .on('change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );

                        column
                            .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                            .draw();
                    });

                column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                    select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')

                });
            });
        }
    });


    $('#selectAll').click(function (e) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('checkedAll')) {

    $('input').prop('checked', false);
        $(this).removeClass('checkedAll');

    } else {
        $('input').prop('checked', true);
        $(this).addClass('checkedAll');
        }
    });

        var serviceURL = '/THPP-ConfigPortal/ProviderContracts/Index/';

        //$("#ID").submit(function () {
            var tableName = "provider_contracts";
            $('#AjaxCall').click(function () {
            $.ajax({         

            url: serviceURL,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

            success: function(result){
                $('#provider_contracts').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {

                     $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(10).text('Approved');


                });
            }

            //sucess:function()
            //{
            //    $('#provider_contracts').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {

            //        var item = $(this).val();

            //        alert(item);
            //    });
            //}

                });

            });

        //});    

});
enter code here

@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.thpp_Business_Config_Self_Service>

<link href="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "ProviderContracts", null, new AjaxOptions()
{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
}, new { id = "ID" }))
{
    <p style="text-align:left">
        <input type="submit" id="AjaxCall" value="Approve" class="btn btn-default" />

    </p>

    <br />
    <br />
    <table id="provider_contracts" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.CheckBox("isApproved", false, new
                 {
                     @id = "selectAll"
                 })
                </th>
                <th>
                    Internal_ID
                </th>
                <th>
                    Type
                </th>
                <th>
                    LOB
                </th>
                <th>
                    Description
                </th>
                <th>
                    Eff_Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    Term_Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    Fee_Sched
                </th>
                <th>
                    Percentage
                </th>
                <th>
                    Conversion
                </th>
                <th>
                    Status
                </th>
                <th>
                    Timely_Filing
                </th>
                <th>
                    Spec.
                </th>

                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>

            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>
                    Internal_ID
                </th>
                <th>
                    Type
                </th>
                <th>
                    LOB
                </th>
                <th>
                    Description
                </th>
                <th>
                    Eff_Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    Term_Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    Fee_Sched
                </th>
                <th>
                    Percentage
                </th>
                <th>
                    Conversion
                </th>
                <th>
                    Status
                </th>
                <th>
                    Timely_Filing
                </th>
                <th>
                    Spec.
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>

        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>

                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Control)

                    <td class="selectAll">

                        @Html.CheckBox("complete", false, new { @class = "complete", id = "complete[]", @value = item.Control })

                    </td>


                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Internal_ID)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type_Indicator)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LOB)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Effective_Date)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Term_Date)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Fee_Sched)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Percentage)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Conversion)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Timely_Filing_Days)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Specialty)
                    </td>

                    <td>

                        <a href="@Url.Action("Edit/" + item.Control, "ProviderContracts") " class="modal-link btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("Create/", "ProviderContracts") " class="modal-link btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("Delete/" + item.Control, "ProviderContracts") " class="modal-link btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>


                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

<script src="~/Scripts/ProviderContracts.js"></script>
```

Comment: Then image you have shown already has Status = Approved for every row so not clear what your asking, but in the ajax success callback, you can always loop through each row in your table, check if the associated checkbox is checked, and update the text of the associated Status column

Comment: That sounds like a solid plan to me. I will have to figure out how tell if that row in the table "is checked" and how to write to the Status column in the datatable.

Comment: You have not shown the html your generating, but if would be along the lines of `$.each('table tr', function(index, row) { var isChecked = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked'); if (isChecked) { $(this).children('td').eq(10).text('Approved'); } });` (but that can be improved bt using class name selectors etc

Comment: Thanks, I am going to use that code snippet you provided  and update this post with my HTML. I'll let you know if I get this working - Best

Answer (score 0):

```
 var serviceURL = '/THPP-ConfigPortal/ProviderContracts/Index/';

            //$("#ID").submit(function () {
                var tableName = "provider_contracts";
                $('#AjaxCall').click(function () {
                $.ajax({         

                url: serviceURL,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                success: function(result){
                    $('#provider_contracts').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {

                         $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(10).text('Approved');


                    });
                }
```

Comment: @Stephen Muecke your comment lead me to the answer !! Thanks Dude!